# How to publish a qt GUI application on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator, publish

When I try to publish a qt application like a simple **"hello world"**
with qtcreator gives me the following error:

```
Publishing is currently not possible for project 'xxxx'.
```

I just want to create an application that can be run another Mac OS without qtcreator.

Comment: i thought you have to just export the project to open it on another system.

Answer (score 0):

You do that from the terminal using the [macdeployqt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html#the-mac-deployment-tool) tool.

Comment: QTDIR/bin/macdeployqt I cannot find this tool.Please help me.thank you so much!

Comment: @user1846851 QTDIR is your Qt installation directory.

Comment: There still have a problem.The qtcreator cannot publish my application.And I cannot get a bundle.there just some .h .pro profile.How can I get a package of my application

Comment: The publish option is gray.cannot be selected.

Comment: @user1846851 It's a command line tool. Has nothing to do with Creator.

Comment: I know,this tool is let the app file convert to dmg. my problem is I do not know how to get the app file,the bundle(just like the exe in windows)